# Page title or URL as a parmeter

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, sitepages, powerapps-canvas

I'm trying to pass either the page URL or Title as a parameter in SharePoint online to a Power app.

It has to be dynamic since I am going to be placing a link to the power app in the footer which will load on different pages.

Here's what I currently have (I changed the URL of the power app for security reasons) https://apps.powerapps.com/play/blahblahblah, *&referur*= **site:{Site.URL}**

The italics is the parametername The bold part is the parmetervalue and the problem. It will only send the exact text.

Is there any way without JavaScript to get either the URL or the title of the current page? What would the link have to look like?

If I do have to use a programing language like JS, does anyone know where I can find an example of how to do this?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible using SharePoint out of the box footer as there is no direct way to get the current page URL.

As you are going to use this on multiple pages, recommend way is to create a SPFx application customizer, use bottom placeholder and create your own custom footer.

You can get the current page title/URL from SPFx context.

**Documentation**: [Use page placeholders in SPFx application customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions)

Here you can find some SPFx extensions sample which will help you to get started with: [SPFx extension samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples)